# getText() returns a blank in Selenium even if the text is not hidden. I also tried JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, gettext

I am trying to match the text and select the check box.
I am trying to get the text or the `innerHTML` from the input tag of type `checkbox`.

I tried `getText()`; it returns blank, `innerHTML`, `innerText` returns `null`.

I am able to fetch the value, and all the other associated attributes of the tag, but not the text.
I tried getting the text by executing the JavaScript code through Selenium, but that is also returning `null` or blank. How can I fix this?

The text is visible - not hidden.

Comment: Try to give some codes that you have written

Comment: Could you provide the HTML code of the element.

Comment: With Java I was having this issue with a BR tag returning empty. Instead of `.getText()` I used `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` which will then return what I was looking for, including any HTML that is invisible or text that is hidden.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087952/how-to-gettext-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try using getAttribute("textContent") or getAttribute("value")

Comment: `getAttribute("textContent")` works for my invisible textarea. Thanks!

Comment: getAttribute("textContent") worked for me also. I wish I found this answer an hour ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public Collection<String> getTextValuesFromSearch(WebElement searchContext) {

    final Collection<String> collectedText = new ArrayList<>();
    final Collection<WebElement> webElementsWithText = searchContext.findElements(By. css/xpath("yourElement"));

    for (final WebElement webElement : webElementsWithText) {

        collectedText.add(webElement.getText());
    }
    return collectedText;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.